# Update Failed! : while install wordpress Themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to install themes in wordpress. When I click install button of them it says update failed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option#1-may be the execution time is slow try to change it

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the `php.ini`

Option#2- download theme(.zip file) from source (maybe wordpress.org or themeforest) and put it into `wp-content/themes/` and replace it your theme with new one